# Добавить уникальные значения из одного в массива в другой JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, сравнение

Добрый день, пару дней мучаюсь, не знаю как реализовать задачу, помогите пожалуйста.

У нас есть два массива:

```
var new_arr1 = [
[0, 1],
[1, 0, 2],
[2, 1, 3],
[3, 2, 4, 6],
[4, 3, 5, 6],
[5, 4],
[6, 3, 4, 7],
[7, 6, 8, 9, 10],
[8, 7, 10],
[9, 7],
[10, 7, 8]
];
```

И

```
var new_arr2 = [
[0],
[1],
[2],
[3],
[4],
[5],
[6],
[7],
[8],
[9],
[10]
];
```

Нужно:

1. Проверить на совпадения элемент new_arr2[line][elem] с
   new_arr1[line2][elem2].
2. Если есть совпадение, то нужно добавить
   уникальные элементы из строки new_arr1[line2] в строку
   new_arr2[line].
3. Продолжить поиск элементов в той же строке
   new_arr2[line] пока они не закончатся.
4. Как только все "пересечения"
   будут найдены, то можно переходить к следующей строке.
5. В итоге должен получиться массив new_arr2, в котором есть все последующие пересечения элемента [0].

Итоговый вид данного примера должен быть типо такого:

```
var new_arr2 = [
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
];
```

Порядок элементов в массивах не важен. Дубликатов быть не должно.

Пробовал циклом for, проблема в том, что строк в массивах может быть за 100, и тогда всё виснет.
Может есть другой какой то выход, а не сравнивать все элементы друг с другом и потом добавлять, удалять дубликаты и снова сравнивать...
Кстати: Первый элемент в не измененном массиве new_arr2(и в массиве new_arr1)   это его номер строки, остальные цифры, это номера строк, с которыми данная строка пересекается.

Вот моё корявенькое решение для 10 строк, оно работает нормально:

```
function chek_all_intersection()
{   
    for ( line = 0; line < new_arr2.length; line++ )
    {
        for ( elem = 0; elem < new_arr2[line].length; elem++ )
        {
            for ( line2 = 0; line2 < new_arr1.length; line2++ )
            {
                for ( elem2 = 0; elem2 < new_arr1[line2].length; elem2++ )
                {
                    if( new_arr1[line2][elem2] == new_arr2[line][elem] )
                    {
                        for( elem_in = 0; elem_in < new_arr1[line2].length; elem_in++ )
                        {
                            if( new_arr1[line2][elem_in] != new_arr2[line][elem] )
                            {
                                new_arr2[line].push( new_arr1[line2][elem_in] );
                                new_remove_double_arr.bind(this)(line);
                                //console.log( "Нужно добавить из строки", line2, "элемент", elem_in, "в строку", line)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Впрочем мне new_arr2 или new_arr1 после этого кода не нужны, если будет какой то третий массив, то мне и с ним будет хорошо. Но главное, чтобы в нем были все "пересечения".

Comment: console.log([...new Set([1,2,3,4,5].concat([1,4,5,6,3,2,2]))]); сравнить два массива и вывести в новый массив уникальные значения

Comment: На просторах интернета я нашел неплохую функцию 
diff = function (a1, a2) {
    return a1.filter( i => !a2.includes(i) ).concat( a2.filter ( i=> !a1.includes(i) ) );
}
Она как раз и выведет уникальные и добавит их в новый массив.

Comment: Какую? хотелось бы увидеть Ваше решение задачи :)

Comment: @ЕгорКушаков, это не очень хорошая функция

Comment: @Grundy это не очень хороший комментарий

Comment: Изначально я не знаю ни сколько строк будет в массивах ни об их "пересечениях". Поэтому нужен вариант, который пройдет по всем элементам и всем строкам.
Главная проблема - с 10 строками проблем нет, проблемы начинаются от 30+, всё лагает.

Comment: У вас по моему проблема не с алгоритмом а с общим подходом к задаче. Почитайте про обработку больших объемов данных. http://w3pro.ru/article/obrabotka-bolshikh-obemov-dannykh-v-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Судя по результату, который должен получиться нужно добавить предварительную обработку `new_arr1`. По сути на каждой итерации для `new_arr2` будут проверяться все элементы из `new_arr1`, следовательно из массива массивов с повторяющимися значениями `new_arr1` можно сделать один набор с уникальными значениями, который потом проверять. Например так:

```
var uniq = [].concat(...new_arr1).reduce((acc,cur)=>(acc[cur]=true, acc),{});
```

Тогда сам процесс будет заключаться в проходу по массиву `new_arr2`, для каждого элемента - добавить к уникальным значениям значения из элемента и вернуть.

Например так:

```js
var new_arr1 = [
  [0, 1],
  [1, 0, 2],
  [2, 1, 3],
  [3, 2, 4, 6],
  [4, 3, 5, 6],
  [5, 4],
  [6, 3, 4, 7],
  [7, 6, 8, 9, 10],
  [8, 7, 10],
  [9, 7],
  [10, 7, 8]
];

var new_arr2 = [
  [0],
  [1],
  [2],
  [3],
  [4],
  [5],
  [6],
  [7],
  [8],
  [9],
  [10]
];

// собираем уникальные значения в `new_arr1`
var uniq = [].concat(...new_arr1).reduce((acc, cur) => (acc[cur] = true, acc), {});

console.log(
  // Бежим по массву new_arr2
  new_arr2.map(a =>
    // выбираем уникальные элементы
    Object.keys(
      // для каждого элемента new_arr2 составляем merge с уникальными из new_arr1
      a.reduce((acc, cur) => (acc[cur] = true, acc), Object.assign({}, uniq))
    )
  ))
```